# takePicture failed with CameraSource

Tags: android, android-camera

I using barcode scanner and when its finished I need the pivture of the barcode.
I took this example:
https://harshitabambure.medium.com/barcode-scanner-and-qr-code-scanner-android-kotlin-b911b1299f65
And the scanner works fine, but my addtion for saving the picture not working and crashes on:

```
cameraSource.takePicture
```

Log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
    at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1508)
    at com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource.takePicture(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@@19.1.3:60)
    at com.example.barcodetst1.MainActivity$setupControls$2.receiveDetections$lambda-2(MainActivity.kt:106)
    at com.example.barcodetst1.MainActivity$setupControls$2.$r8$lambda$7MpLFBTAl5Z8Yg1xMhYmW99yc8s(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.barcodetst1.MainActivity$setupControls$2$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Main Class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val requestCodeCameraPermission = 1001
private lateinit var cameraSource: CameraSource
private lateinit var barcodeDetector: BarcodeDetector
private var scannedValue = ""
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@MainActivity, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        askForCameraPermission()
    } else {
        setupControls()
    }

    val aniSlide: Animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this@MainActivity, R.anim.scanner_animation)
    binding.barcodeLine.startAnimation(aniSlide)
}


private fun setupControls() {
    barcodeDetector = BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS).build()

    cameraSource = CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
        .setRequestedPreviewSize(1920, 1080)
        .setAutoFocusEnabled(true) //you should add this feature
        .build()

    binding.cameraSurfaceView.holder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
            try {
                //Start preview after 1s delay
                cameraSource.start(holder)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, format: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {
            try {
                cameraSource.start(holder)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
            cameraSource.stop()
        }
    })


    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(object : Detector.Processor<Barcode> {
        override fun release() {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Scanner has been closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }

        override fun receiveDetections(detections: Detections<Barcode>) {
            val barcodes = detections.detectedItems
            if (barcodes.size() == 1) {
                scannedValue = barcodes.valueAt(0).rawValue

                //Don't forget to add this line printing value or finishing activity must run on main thread
                runOnUiThread {

                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "value- $scannedValue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //Save Image
                    cameraSource.takePicture(null) {
                        val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(it, 0, it.size)
                        binding.imageViewTest.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, binding.imageViewTest.width, binding.imageViewTest.height, false))

                    }
                    //cameraSource.stop()
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "value- else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }
    })
}

private fun askForCameraPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        this@MainActivity,
        arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
        requestCodeCameraPermission
    )
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == requestCodeCameraPermission && grantResults.isNotEmpty()) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            setupControls()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    cameraSource.stop()
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
please try this
<code> 
  private void showCameraDialogShopImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo",
            "Cancel"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(KycVerifyDetails.this);
    builder.setTitle("Change Shop Image");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                    //Check permissions for Android 6.0+
                    if(!checkExternalStoragePermission()){
                        return;
                    }
                }
                values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "MyPicture");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Photo taken on " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULTSHOPIMAGE);

            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                showCameraDialog();
                getLastLocation();
            } else {
                //code for deny
            }
            break;
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
       
            //shop image
        case PICTURE_RESULTSHOPIMAGE:
            if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULTSHOPIMAGE){
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        thumbnailShopImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                        shopviewImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnailShopImage);
                        latitudeTxt.setText("Latitude  : "+latitudeStr);
                        longitudeTxt.setText("Longitude : "+longitudeStr);
                        imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
    


    }
}



public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

private boolean checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Permission not granted.");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "You already have permission!");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

  


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context) {
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentAPIVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                });
                android.app.AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

</code>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please [edit] it.